# How to add the little X on the right corner that the youtube notification has when casting?

Tags: android

When casting to a chromecast device the youtube app puts up what I think is a big view notification. It also has a little X on the top corner and I just can't figure out how they are displaying it? The X is the only way to dismiss the notification, you can't click clear all to get rid of it.

Here is an image of what I'm talking about, it is the X on top right corner of the youtube notification. [image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a custom view, so you can design it the way you want.